# How to extract lines above a match using regex and R?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to match some specific string using R and keep only the line above that match, here is some example data. Having a file with hundreds of similar cases:

```
first_case<- data.frame(line = 

             c("#John Wayne: Su, 11.01.2013 08:24:42#
                He is present / I guess, Does great job
                --------------------------------------------------
                #Michal Thorn: Fr, 12.09.2015 17:23:01#
                Works quite frequently with people
                --------------------------------------------------
                #Sandra Nunes: Mo, 20.05.2011 09:00:29#
                She has some new clients"))



second_case<- data.frame(line = 

                c("#Boris Jonson: Mo, 30.09.2017 09:20:42#
                He is present
                --------------------------------------------------
                #Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#
                Does great job
                --------------------------------------------------
                #Michael Bissping: Mo, 25.03.2012 10:00:29#
                Hard to count on"))



third_case<- data.frame(line = 

              c("#Isabelle Warren: Sa, 02.12.2013 02:24:42#
                 Not around / anymore
               --------------------------------------------------
                 #Tobias Maker: Mo, 02.03.2013 10:23:01#
                 Works quite frequently with people
               --------------------------------------------------
                 #Toe Michael : Mo, 20.05.2011 09:00:29#
                 She has some new clients & Does great job"))

all_cases <- rbind(first_case,second_case,third_case)
```

Here I try to filter those lines which are 1 line above:

`Does great job`

By looking if `Does great job` ends with new line and take the first line above:

```
dplyr::filter(all_cases, grepl("((.*\n){1})Does great job",line))
```

Expected results:

```
first_case<- data.frame(line = 
                      c("#John Wayne: Su, 11.01.2013 08:24:42#"))
second_case<- data.frame(line = 
                       c("#Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#"))
third_case<- data.frame(line = 
                      c("#Toe Michael : Mo, 20.05.2011 09:00:29#"))

expected_result <- rbind(first_case,second_case,third_case)

1   #John Wayne: Su, 11.01.2013 08:24:42#
2   #Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#
3   #Toe Michael : Mo, 20.05.2011 09:00:29#
```

Unfortunately, this returns zero rows. Appreciate any insights!

Comment: Could you please add the expected results?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just a second

Comment: Why do you use the word "filter" if, judging by the title, you want to *extract* a part of the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I would like to keep only the line above `Does great job`

Comment: Your data set hase only three lines, each one with three persons, shouldn't it have 9 lines unstead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try :

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

all_cases %>% transmute(x=str_extract(line,".*(?=\n.*?Does great job)"))

#                                                         x
#1                    #John Wayne: Su, 11.01.2013 08:24:42#
#2                    #Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#
#3                  #Toe Michael : Mo, 20.05.2011 09:00:29#
```

Improved solution, in order to exploit independantly each line of each bunch of three persons :

```
all_cases %>% separate(line,c("a","b","c"),sep="-{3,}") %>%
  gather(k,v,a,b,c) %>%
  transmute(x=str_extract(v,".*(?=\n.*?Does great job)")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(x))
```

Comment: Hi, I have two short questions concerning your first answer:
First, I don't understand why in the third case your solution does not return all the lines before 'Does great job' (i.e. including the lines about Isabelle Warren and Tobias Marker).
Second: Why do you need second questionmark (?) in your regex. The effect seems to be the same if you just write `".*(?=\n.*Does great job)"`.
It would be great if you could give a short answer. Thank you

Comment: @Cettt The previous lines are not returned because the default behaviour of the dot is not matching the new lines. The second question mark is necessary to get a "lazy" behaviour for the * : if the question mark is not present a repeated dot will "eat" all the charcaters until the end of the line including the wanted string.

Comment: It does not matter if you use `.*`  or `.*?` if you do not know where the `Does great job` appears. If you are sure it is always closer to the start of the line, use `.*?`, else use `.*`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You're right. Shame on me. The only point is that the question mark makes the search more efficient reducing the need of saving contexts for backtracking. But one could expect that optimisation of reach takes care of that.

Comment: *The only point is that the question mark makes the search more efficient reducing the need of saving contexts for backtracking* - it only makes it efficient ***if*** the string appears closer to the start of the line, else, it is making it more inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one base R approach using `strsplit`.  We can form a list/vector of lines, and then directly use `grep` to find the index of the line matching `Does great job`.  Then, just return the line which immediately precedes that.

```
line <- "#Boris Jonson: Mo, 30.09.2017 09:20:42#
         He is present
         --------------------------------------------------
         #Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#
         Does great job
         --------------------------------------------------
         #Michael Bissping: Mo, 25.03.2012 10:00:29#
         Hard to count on"

terms <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\n"))
terms[grep("Does great job", terms) - 1]

[1] "                #Jacky Fine: Th, 02.02.2013 18:23:01#"
```

### Demo

There are a number of edge cases which my answer does not cover, the first being the match logic.  What should happen if the search term matches more than once, or not at all?  Also, how specific should the pattern used in `grep` be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `(.+)\n(.*[dD]oes great job.*)`. First capturing group `\1` will be what you need.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7MlnZ/1)

**Note**: I assumed, that `.` won't match `\n`.

Comment: While your pattern might be usable in certain APIs, this is an R question, and most likely just giving a pattern won't help much.